Inequality with medians
It is well known that in any triangle $\triangle ABC$ with side lengths $a,b,c$ and medians $m_a,m_b,m_c$ inequality
\begin{equation}
\frac{3}{4}(a+b+c)<m_a+m_b+m_c<a+b+c 
\end{equation}
holds. This formula for $m_a$ is well known too (for $m_b, m_c$ similarly):
$$
m_a=\frac{\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}}{2}.
$$
Any idea how to prove $\frac{3}{4}(a+b+c)<m_a+m_b+m_c$ just using formulas for medians, in other words purely algebraicly? I tried to use identity
$m^2_a+m^2_b+m^2_c=\frac{3}{4}(a^2+b^2+c^2),$
which is straightforward consequence of formulas for medians, but I failed.

What proof the inequality do you know? Where do you get stuck when trying to convert that into an algebraic proof?

We claim that:
$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{2}{3}m_a+\frac{2}{3}m_b > c\\
      \frac{2}{3}m_b+\frac{2}{3}m_c > a\\
      \frac{2}{3}m_c+\frac{2}{3}m_a > b
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
$$
Now:
$$
\begin{equation}
3c < 2m_a + 2m_b\\
\iff 9c^2 < (2m_a)^2 + (2m_b)^2 + 2 (2m_a)(2m_b)\\
\iff 9c^2 < (2b^2+2c^2-a^2)+(2c^2+2a^2-b^2) +  2 \sqrt{(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)(2c^2+2a^2-b^2)}\\
\iff (5c^2-a^2-b^2)^2 <4(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)(2c^2+2a^2-b^2)\\
\iff 9c^4-10a^2c^2-10b^2c^2+a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2< 4(4c^4+2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-2a^4-2b^4+5a^2b^2)\\
\iff a^4+b^4+c^4<2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)\\
\iff (a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)>0
\end{equation}
$$
The last inequality holds because of the triangle inequality. The second and third inequalities can also be proven in a similar fashion. Finally, we sum the three inequalities and obtain: $\frac{4}{3}(m_a+m_b+m_c)>a+b+c$.
